# JSF How to allow user to define path where the certain file is

Tags: jsf

Ok so I need to get path of the file. Only path. I actually need path to XML file in user pc (specific web app). There is option simply making upload file and save only path of it, but I'm interested is there any "path picker" in JSF or should I use work around.

Comment: sorry, I think I don't understand your question. Would you mind giving us a little bit more info?

Comment: Rewritten it hopefully more clear :)

Comment: I see. If you want a file picker for the client side (choose a file in your user machine), there's no way using pure JSF, because JSF will delegate to the browser to open the native file chooser provided by the underline OS. To change this, you'd have to integrate to some client-side technology such as flash or applets. Now, if what you want is to expose your server-side file system using JSF (maybe not a good idea), you can try something like a tree component backed by java's File classes.

Comment: As deep I go into this as fast I'm starting to think I should reconsider technology.. :D

Comment: I won't tell you a lie. JSF does not solves everything :-) in fact, web technologies were already kind of a hell when we had only a few browsers. Now, with tablets and smartphones, I think it's only getting to be even worse :-)